# How to declare dependencies from different git commits in a Makefile?

Tags: git, makefile

I am trying automate the bootstrapping of a compiler, from version `n` to version `n+1`. The problem is that the compiler is (partly) written in the language it compiles, so not only it is itself a dependency for building itself, but also modifying the source code of the compiler modifies both the syntax of the language (and hence the syntax of that source code) *and* the semantics of the produced code. Both could change when passing from version `n` to `n+1`.

I have looked at several possible solutions for this problem (mainly, how other compilers do it), and I have adopted the following scheme:

- assume a binary of compiler version `n` is available (a binary of version `0` has been produced "by hand", and binaries have been rolled since then);
- write a version `n.5` of the compiler, which uses the syntax and semantics of the language defined by compiler version `n`, but itself parses syntax of language version `n+1`, and uses semantics of version `n+1`;
- compile it using compiler version `n` to get a compiler version `n.5`;
- write a version `n+1` of the compiler, which uses the syntax and the semantics it defines itself;
- use compiler version `n.5` to compiler version `n+1`.

I now have a binary of compiler version `n+1`, and the source code is written in the language version `n+1`. I can now store this *somewhere* to be used to build version `n+2`, and so on.

Ideally, this could be done in a single pass:

- compiler: version `n`; source code: version `n`.
- *I write compiler version `n.5`* -> compiler: version `n`; source code: version `n.5`.
- *I build the project with the available compiler* -> compiler: version `n.5`; source code: version `n.5`.
- *I write compiler version `n+1`* -> compiler: version `n.5`; source code: version `n+1`.
- *I build the project with the available compiler* -> compiler: version `n+1`; source code: version `n+1`.

But in reality, one might (silently) introduce bugs in the version `n.5` of the source code, making the compiler version `n.5` bugged. Then, we trying to compile version `n+1`, it fails, because the compiler is bugged (or worse, it doesn't fail, but introduces a bug in compiler version `n+1` which makes it diverge from the source code version `n+1`, and so forth up to version `n+1000` when you realize there is a bug...). This means that all the versions of the source code should be available independently, so that one can back up, patch the bug in version `n.5`, then rebuild everything.

To do so, while developing version `n+1` from version `n`, assuming I'm standing at a commit of the compiler repo which corresponds to version `n`, I create two branches: one for version `n.5`, and one for version `n+1`. I write the code for both versions of the compiler, then build the project as mentioned before. This allows each branch to evolve as I need more features or patch more bugs, and once it is finished, I can merge everything to get version `n+1`.

My problem is: how to get `make` to understand that some dependencies are in an other commit than the current commit? In particular, the compiler version `n+1` has, as dependency, `compiler-vn.5`, whose source code is in an other branch. Is this even possible?

Comment: I would think the different bootstrap stages exist *simultaneously* in a single commit, so that you aren't having to checkout different commits during the build process. I.e, `n`, `n.5`, and `n+1` are *not* different versions of the compiler; they are different *stages* of the source required to build a single version of the compiler.

Comment: If you avoid making *incompatible* changes, at least to some sufficiently powerful core subset of the language, then you don't need to introduce `n.5` versions of the compiler.  Just be sure to write the compiler in version `n` (or `m < n`) of the compatible language core.

Comment: ... and if your language is not stable enough for that, then perhaps it would be better to not write the compiler in its own target language.

Comment: @chepner that's an interesting idea, but I don't see how to make it happen without having, at each commit of my repo, the entirety of the history (or at least every major version) of the compiler, because if I need to have at hand versions `n`, `n.5` and `n+1`, then I also need versions `0` through `n+1` (because the idea is to repeat the compilation to bootstrap from version `0` to the actual one). Ideally, let git handle all the versioning, instead of making it explicit in each commit.

Comment: @JohnBollinger indeed, I currently use a relatively small subset of the language in question to implement (a part of) the compiler, but allowing arbitrary changes in the language itself during development and still being able to bootstrap it automatically is one of my challenges for this project, so, even though it might not be the easiest solution, that's still what I want to strive for unless it's really *too* hard.

Comment: Besides, the language itself is, indeed, not really stable right now (even its syntax changes quite regularly) because I haven't reached a satisfying status yet. But, it's not a general-purpose language: it's a language specifically designed for parsing and abstract syntax rewriting, which is especially well-suited for what I am doing :) When the language didn't have enough features, everything was written in a "regular" language, but since I've bootstrapped it I've reduced by an order of magnitude all logic that that language can handle. All this to say that, despite its instability, there...

Comment: ...are some practical advantages to use the language itself to compile it, which (so far) have outweigh its disadvantages (its high instability, for instance).

Comment: The very definition of a bootstrapping compiler is one that has several stages. Don't confuse the stages with *versions*. (Each commit is, in a sense, a different version of *all* the stages.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`make` deals with dependencies that are files on the filesystem.  That's it.  It doesn't know about anything else.  So if you can transform your branch requirements into files on the filesystem and represent their "out of date" / "up to date" qualities as timestamps on these files, make can help you with it.  If not, it can't.

For example, if you keep the SHA of the branch as of the time you last built it in a file, then you can have a rule with a recipe that checks to see if that is the current SHA of the head of the branch.  if it is, the recipe does nothing (doesn't change the file--note it's not good enough to just write the same SHA into the file!  That still changes the timestamp.  You have to avoid touching the file at all) and the file's timestamp does not change and nothing is out of date.  If the SHA is different you update the contents of the file with the new SHA, now the file is new and anything that depends on that file will be rebuilt.

Or something like that.

**ETA**

I don't have time to write a completely working example, and StackOverflow is a place to ask specific questions about specific technical problems, not a place to get a completely working example from scratch.  But this can get you started: this will get the SHA of the given branch into the variable `my-branch_SHA`:

```
my-branch_SHA := $(shell git rev-parse my-branch)
```

now you can write a rule like this:

```
my-branch_FILE: FORCE
        test '$(my_branch_SHA)' = "$$(cat $@)" \
            || echo '$(my_branch_SHA)' > $@

FORCE:;
```

The `FORCE` trick is documented in the GNU Make manual; it basically gets make to always run that rule to check whether the file is out of date.  But the recipe says "if the values are different, update the file" (which will change its timestamp); if the values are the same nothing happens so the timestamp is not updated.

Now if you add `my-branch_FILE` as a prerequisite to some other target, that target will be considered out of date (and so its recipe will be run) if the branch SHA is different.

If you have lots of these branches you might want to use various other tricks to avoid code duplication.  You can probably get some useful ideas in this series of blog posts: https://make.mad-scientist.net/category/metaprogramming/  Definitely prefer the simplest ones that get the job done: everyone jumps immediately for `eval` but it is very tricky to use; the other options are much simpler.

If you run into problems ask a new question showing your example code and asking specifically about the problem you have.

Comment: Using the commit hash of the currently-built compiler for a given version seems like a very promising solution to my problem. Unfortunately, I don't know how to tell `make` that a recipe should consider hashes respectively written in a file and given by `git` instead of timestamps. Would you mind showing me a small example, or giving some more details?

Comment: I think I wasn't clear.  Make won't ever consider the content of a file, at all.  See the first sentence or two of my answer.  Make only considers the last modified timestamp of the file.  It's up to you to write a recipe (shell commands) that translate "this SHA is different" into "this file has been updated".  I will add an example.

Comment: That `FORCE` trick is exactly what I was missing to complete the rest of the puzzle, I guess I should have RTFM. Thanks!